# How can I use the Lagrange Inversion Theorem?

Tags: functions, inverse

I have a function $f(x)= x(\ln(x\ln x))$ and I want to use the Lagrange Inversion theorem to find its inverse $g(x)$ centered around a point $a$. The formula states that: $$g(x)=a+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\lim_{x\to a}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\left(\frac{x-a}{f(x)-f(a)}\right)^n \frac{(x-f(a))^n}{n!}\right).$$
I don't really know how to evaluate the limit. I have tried taking the limit before the taking the derivative, which is $$\lim_{x\to e}\left(\frac{x-e}{x(\ln(x\ln x))-e}\right)^n$$ which evaluates to $1/3^n$.
I have tried taking the derivative first, for the first two values of $n$ I got $\frac {-1}{18e}$ and $\frac {-1}{27e}$ After this it becomes too slow to compute the third derivative manually or even in Wolfram Alpha, continuing the pattern I would say it would be $\frac {-1}{36e}$ but I truly have no idea. None of these alternatives seem to give me what I am looking for, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The formula is evaluating derivatives at $x=a$, so you must do the derivatives first. Also, there does not seem to be an expansion with simple-to-evaluate coefficients of the form $f^{-1}(x)=\sum a_n x^n$. However, [this expansion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x+ln%28x+ln%28x%29%29%2Cx%3D1%2Blim%5Bsum%5B1%2Fn%21+D%5Be%5Ew+%28e%5E%28-4+e%5E-w%29+e%5E-w%29%5En%2C%7Bw%2Cn-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C9%7D%5D%2Cw-%3E0.0%5D) is $f^{-1}(x)$ in a slightly different form. The series coefficients are expressible as a single/double sum. Would you like this expansion as an answer?